# rounded rectangle as a background in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to do an overlay, but it doesn't work ,
[image: The Bottom part problem]
That part on the bottom keeps bugging me.
is there any other method beside doing an overlay of a rectangle??

```
ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .foregroundColor(Color("Hello"))
                        .frame(height: 700, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                        .overlay(
                            VStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                    .frame(width:381, height: 130.36, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .shadow(radius: 4,y:3)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                                    .overlay(
                                            HStack {
                                                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                                                    ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Keuangan",ButtonIcon: "creditcard.fill")
                                                }
                                                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                                                    ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Penjurusan",ButtonIcon: "figure.walk")
                                                }
                                                Button(action: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Action@*/{}/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                                                    ButtonBig(ButtonText: "Status",ButtonIcon: "person.crop.circle.badge.plus")
                                                }
                                        }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()))
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                                    .frame(width:381, height: 535, alignment: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.center/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                                    .shadow(radius: 4,y:3)
                                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                            }
```

[image]

I wanted to create something like that basically

if there's a library for it, please do tell me. Thank you

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score -1):

Try these 2 modifiers:

```
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
.clipped()
```